# How to use -r @cypress/instrument-cra for code coverage without react-scripts

Tags: reactjs, cypress, code-coverage, react-scripts

```
 "start": "node index.js",
```

How do I add  `-r @cypress/instrument-cra` in "start"?
According to the documents given [here](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/09/05/cypress-code-coverage-for-create-react-app-v3/) we need `react-scripts` but in my use case I don't have it.

Comment: `@cypress/instrument-cra` adds `babel-plugin-istanbul` to the webpack config. Do you use webpack in your project?

Comment: Yes, I do use webpack in my project

Comment: You can replicate the steps `@cypress/instrument-cra` take in your own webpack config. Please add the webpack config to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `webpack.config.js` file (webpack v5) this is how you would add the `babel-plugin-istanbul` plugin.

Note, I only show the relevant section of `module.rules` which you will have to *carefully* find in your config.

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
            plugins: ['babel-plugin-istanbul'],
          },
        },
      },

    ],
  },

}
```

Of course, you will need to install [babel-plugin-istanbul](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-istanbul)

```js
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-istanbul
```

If you have `.babelrc`, add it to that file

```js
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [ "istanbul" ]
    }
  }
}
```